itex8 htmlpdf - HTML syntax to add alt text for a svg element
Using itex + pdfHTML convert HTML to Accssible PDF with svg element with alt text.
I'm using itext 8 and latest htmlPDF library .
I have designed an html sample that has these elements
 <p>Remember to keep it simple for PDF/UA compliance.</p>
    <p id="circle">A red circle</p>
    <svg role="img" width="100" height="100" aria-labelledby="circle" alt="pippo"> 
    <title id="unique-id-123">A cowboy riding a triceratops</title>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red">
    </circle>
    </svg>

running
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf

i got the PDF, but it has not alt text.

how is the right syntax to use?

What happens when you simply remove the aria-labelledby attribute, and the alt? The <title> element is the intended means to provide an accessible name for SVG.

@Andy  i tryed  many combo.... but i got  always  sameresult... nothing change

@KJ yes.... but pdfHTML should automatize the process....  what you post is a manual solution
